# Display custom taxonomy in DESC within the original loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem. I would like the have the posts of this loop show in descending order. But for a plugin I have to stick to the original loop. So I can't use new WP_Query or query_posts because this overrides the original loop.

This is my loop.

```
<div id="main-filter">
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

 ?>


    <!-- Test if the current post is in category 3. -->
    <!-- If it is, the div box is given the CSS class "post-cat-three". -->
    <!-- Otherwise, the div box is given the CSS class "post". -->

    <?php if ( in_category( '3' ) ) : ?>
        <div class="post-cat-three">
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="post post-item">
    <?php endif; ?>


    <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->

    <div class="ref-wrap">
        <div class="col-sm-2 thumb-mobile">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(200,200)); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="entry">
                <?php $bedrijf = get_field('naam_bedrijf'); ?>
                <?php $feest = get_field('feest'); ?>
                <?php $geschreven = get_field('geschreven_door'); ?>
                <?php $datum = get_field('datum_referentie'); ?>
                <?php $tekst = get_field('volledige_tekst'); ?>
                <?php $link = get_field('mylink'); ?>
                <?php echo '<p>Bedrijfsnaam: ' . $bedrijf . '</p>'; ?>
                <?php $post_object = get_field('mylink');
                    if( $post_object ): $post = $post_object; setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

                    <p>Feest type: <a style="color:#ff6600" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo '<p>Naam: ' . $geschreven . '</p>'; ?>
                <?php echo '<p>Datum: ' . $datum . '</p>'; ?>
                <?php echo '<p class="mobile-j">' . $tekst . '</p>'; ?>
                <?php echo '<p>' . wp_review_show_total() . '</p>'; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>


    <!-- Display a comma separated list of the Post's Categories. -->
    </div> <!-- closes the first div box -->


    <!-- Stop The Loop (but note the "else:" - see next line). -->

 <?php endwhile; else : ?>

    <!-- The very first "if" tested to see if there were any Posts to -->
    <!-- display.  This "else" part tells what do if there weren't any. -->
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>


    <!-- REALLY stop The Loop. -->
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
</div>
```

Is there anyway I can order this loop in DESC?

** Little edit: I don't know if this matters but this is the custom taxonomy: referentie_type

Answer (score 0):

You can put everything in an array instead of outputting it, then loop through that array in reverse and only then output it.

Your constraints make this pretty much impossibly to do in a neat way.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please point me in the right way. I did thought I would have to use an array. Does this require $args in some form?

I know that the plug-in gives me allot of constraints.